# How to do Horizon authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-authentication, google-authentication, horizon

I have an horizon app and I have 3 questions regarding authentication:

1.) Is it possible to login with just username and password? If yes, where can I find some snippet or example of that?

2.) I try to follow the documentation and configure facebook login button, but after horizon.authEndpoint(‘facebook').subscribe((endpoint)… I’m just getting redirected to facebook page without returning to my app. Is there an example of how to do it somewhere?

3.)I also try to configure google login and I get the following error:

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, https://.../horizon/google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/... to update the authorized redirect URIs.

Tried every possible variation in google console but with no success.

I configured https, added the tokens to config, configured oauth and redirect uris both in facebook and google.

My Login page:

```
var Login = React.createClass({
    login: function() {
        horizon.authEndpoint('facebook').subscribe((endpoint) => {
            window.location.pathname = endpoint;
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            ...
            <Link className="dark button" to="#" onClick={this.login}>Login!</Link>
            ...
```

Comment: Hey Alexarsh, did you setup your `callback_uri` correctly?

Comment: I think so. I can see it coorectly on /horizon/auth_methods